# How to run Shiny app during RStudio project creation from template?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I am creating a custom RStudio Project Template as detailed [here](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudio-extensions/rstudio_project_templates.html).

I have everything working to create a new project, and I also have the Shiny app working by itself.

However, I would now like to synchronously run the app in what amounts to my `hello_world()` function in the above webpage.

I can write wrapper functions around my Shiny app that work as desired outside of the context of making a new project from a template via the RStudio menus, but in the context of creating a new project, it is as if the line to run the app is not present as no app appears, and there are no messages, warnings, or errors issued.

```r
# function works as expected outside context of creating a new project
run_app <- function() {
  ui <- shiny::fluidPage(shiny::titlePanel("New Project"))
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    session$onSessionEnded(function() {
      shiny::stopApp()
    })
  }
  shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server,
                  options = list(launch.browser = TRUE))
}

# but nothing Shiny related happens if called within the new project creation function
# the new project creation process continues as if the call to start the app is not present
hello_world <- function(path, ...) {
  run_app()
}
```

Is it possible to run a Shiny app during project creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`?shiny::shinyApp`

> Normally when this function is used at the R console, the Shiny app object is automatically passed to the print() function, which runs the app. If this is called in the middle of a function, the value will not be passed to print() and the app will not be run. To make the app run, pass the app object to print() or runApp().

The app runs correctly in its self contained function because the returned value is invisibly passed to print, but this does not happen when the function contains additional code.

Therefore, a solution is to wrap the function call in a `print()`.

```r
hello_world <- function(path, ...) {
  print(run_app())
}
```